# I can't create an Angular File

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

```
PS D:\AngularCalismalar> ng new intro

Node.js version v17.1.0 detected.

Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.

? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes

? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS

CREATE intro/angular.json (3033 bytes)

CREATE intro/package.json (1069 bytes)

CREATE intro/README.md (1051 bytes)

CREATE intro/tsconfig.json (863 bytes)

CREATE intro/.editorconfig (274 bytes)

CREATE intro/.gitignore (620 bytes)

CREATE intro/.browserslistrc (600 bytes)

CREATE intro/karma.conf.js (1422 bytes)

CREATE intro/tsconfig.app.json (287 bytes)

CREATE intro/tsconfig.spec.json (333 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/index.html (291 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/main.ts (372 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/polyfills.ts (2338 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/styles.css (80 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/test.ts (745 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/environments/environment.ts (658 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/app/app.component.html (23364 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1070 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/app/app.component.ts (209 bytes)

CREATE intro/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)



- Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [

npm WARN cleanup   [

npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules',

npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\AngularCalismalar\intro\node_modules\esbuild-windows-64\esbuild.exe'] {

npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,

npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',

npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',

npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\esbuild-windows64\\esbuild.exe'

npm WARN cleanup     }

npm WARN cleanup   ],

npm WARN cleanup   [

npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\postcss-lab-function',

npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\AngularCalismalar\intro\node_modules\postcss-lab-function\node_modules\postcss\lib\list.js'] {

npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,

npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',

npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',

npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\postcss-lab-function\\node_modules\\postcss\\lib\\list.js'

npm WARN cleanup     }

npm WARN cleanup   ],

npm WARN cleanup   [

npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\postcss-initial',

npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\AngularCalismalar\intro\node_modules\postcss-initial\node_modules\postcss\lib\node.js'] {

npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,

npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',

npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',

npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\postcss-initial\\node_modules\\postcss\\lib\\node.js'

npm WARN cleanup     }

npm WARN cleanup   ],

npm WARN cleanup   [

npm WARN cleanup     'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\postcss-pseudo-class-any-link',

npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\AngularCalismalar\intro\node_modules\postcss-pseudo-class-any-link\node_modules\postcss\lib\list.js'] {

npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,

npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',

npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',

npm WARN cleanup       path: 'D:\\AngularCalismalar\\intro\\node_modules\\postcss-pseudo-class-any-link\\node_modules\\postcss\\lib\\list.js'

npm WARN cleanup     }

npm WARN cleanup   ]

npm WARN cleanup ]

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')




npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Furkan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-18T15_09_48_979Z-debug.log

× Package install failed, see above.
```

The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like angular CLI is incompatible with node version 17^x

> Node.js version v17.1.0 detected.
>
> Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not
> be used for production. For more information, please see
> https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.

What worked for me was using node 16 Or node 14.
If you installed node with nvm, you can simply use

```
$ nvm install 16
$ nvm use 16
```

This will make set your node.js version

For more info you can refer to nvm's github page: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Teşekkürler deneyeceğim Türk olmanız ayrı sevindirdi :)